# Determining a row's referenced row for another sheet?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table that includes an "inventory" item's name, as well as its base weight and associated carbs, protein, fat, etc. On another sheet, there's a table that references the inventory item's name, and once I input the actual weight, I'd like my other calculated columns to automatically figure out the carbs, protein, fat, etc. for that selected item and weight. For example...

My "inventory" sheet:

```
Item                      Amount   Unit   Calories   Carbs   Protein   Fat
Chicken Thigh (w/ Bone)   1        oz     37         0       3.73      2.3
```

And my list of items eaten, sold, whichever: **This is the rendered table**

```
Item:                     Measure   Unit   Carbs   Protein   Fat
Chicken Thigh (w/ Bone)   4.6
```

And the raw formulas, or what I think they may be: **I have no idea how to automatically select calories/carbs/etc to use for calculations :(**

```
Item:           Measure   Unit   ... Carbs  ... Protein  ... Fat
=Inventory.A2   4.6       =Sheet/Row of A2's E column * B2
```

...anyone know how to do this in excel? Is it even possible?

Comment: For example, on the "list of items eaten": A1 is "Item", A2 is "=Inventory.A2", and on the Inventory sheet: A1 is also "Item", and D2 is "37". I figured out the issue tho... I just needed to look at vlookup()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Measure` is in B1, `Unit` in C1, you are not interested in `Calories` (so D1 is blank), `Carbs`/`Protein`/`Fat` are in E1:G1 respectively, then in C2:

```
=(IF(C$1="","",IF(ISTEXT(VLOOKUP($A2,Inventory!$A:$G,COLUMN(),0)),VLOOKUP($A2,Inventory!$A:$G,COLUMN(),0),$B2*VLOOKUP($A2,Inventory!$A:$G,COLUMN(),0))))
```

and copied across to G2 might suit.